# Adding 20 textViews in Android using Java

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop

I am new to Android programming and currently trying to understand implementing simple Java in it.
What I am trying to do is to understand how to add 20 textViews in Android studio. I mean, what is the best choice here. 
Is it:

a) Manually add 20 textViews and when I click on button A all the textViews will update with a formula. I believe this will create unnecessary java code and repetition.

b) Create a for loop, add one textView and then update automatically via a method. What I have done so far. Code underneath (immagine there is a button connected to the MainCalculate ID:

```
double realPrice = 10;
double total = (realPrice * 2)+1;
double increase = 0.1;
TextView percentageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentageTextViewID);


public void MainCalculate (View view) {

    MarketValueAnswer.setText(Double.toString(marketValueAnswer));

    for (double i=realPrice; i<=total; i+=increase) {

        double formula = ((realPrice*increase) + realPrice);
        increase+=0.05;
        percentageTextView.append("\n" + formula);

    }
```

Thanks and best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to add 20 TextViews you can do it like this.
The function calculation() is called when a butten is clicked.

```
double realPrice = 10;
double total = (realPrice * 2)+1;
double increase = 0.1;

private void calculation() {

    for (double i=realPrice; i<=total; i+=increase) {

        double formula = ((realPrice*increase) + realPrice);
        increase+=0.05;
        try {
            TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
            txtView.setText(Double.toString(formula));
            ll.addView(txtView);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }
}
```

This will really add 20 TextViews, it may take a little bit depending on your device hardware (better implementing a AsynchTask for this). 
Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: Ok, you asked my question. I wanted to understand if I should use a for loop or manually add 20 textViews.So the answer is "use loop" and then format them in xml / java. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is. See my example postet below for the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better approach using AsynchTask. This will prevent your app from freezing.

```
calculation myCalc = new calculation(this);
myCalc.execute();
```

Here is the AsyncTask class

```
private class calculation extends AsyncTask<Void, Double, Void> {
        //we need this context for the TextView instantiation

    private Context mContext;

    private calculation(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        for (double i=realPrice; i<=total; i+=increase) {
            double formula = ((realPrice*increase) + realPrice);
            increase+=0.05;
            publishProgress(formula);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Double... s) {
        try {
            TextView txtView = new TextView(mContext);
            txtView.setText(Double.toString(s[0]));
            ll.addView(txtView);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }
}
```

Best Solution use a ScrollView with a LineraLayout inside

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create text view through loops. Its a better approach.